# Is there a way to run this Python snippet faster?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, series

```
from collections import defaultdict
dct = defaultdict(list)
for n in range(len(res)):
    for i in indices_ordered:
        dct[i].append(res[n][i])
```

Note that `res` is a list of pandas Series of length 5000, and `indices_ordered` is a list of strings of length 20000. It takes 23 minutes in my Mac (2.3 GHz Intel Core i5 and 16 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3) to run this code. I am pretty new to Python, but I feel a more clever coding (maybe less looping) would help a lot.

---

Edit:

Here is an example of how to create data (`res` and `indices_ordered`) to be able to run above snippet (which is slightly changed to access the only field rather than by field name since I could not find how to construct inline a Series with a field name)

```
import random, string, pandas
index_sz = 20000
res_sz = 5000
indices_ordered = [''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(10)) for i in range(index_sz)]
res = [pandas.Series([random.randint(0,10) for i in range(index_sz)], index = random.sample(indices_ordered, index_sz)) for i in range(res_sz)]
```

Comment: Can you add a sample value for "res"? It becomes easier to visualize what you are trying to do.

Comment: We can't see what `indices_ordered` is, or any example of expected input and output

Comment: Use list comprehension: `[res[n].score[i] for i in indices_ordered for n in range(len(res))]` . Not improved, but, just as an option

Comment: what is the purpose of indices_ordered ?.

Comment: If you use pandas, you should stay within pandas. A pandas dataframe can be seen as both a dict and a list, so there's no need to create all those plain Python objects. Pleas post an example with a short Series and some indices and what the desired output should be.

Comment: Edited the question to include some sample data. Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm getting `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'score'` if I try to run your code on the generated data. (I reduced the `index_sz` outer loop to 100 to make the time managable.)

Comment: Yeah the problem is that, i could not find how to create a list of series with a field name in a loop, so I had to change the actual snippet to access the only field rather than by field name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that you iterate over `indices_ordered` for every single value. Just drop `indices_ordered`. Stripping it *way* back in orders of magnitude to test the timings:

```
import random
import string

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from collections import defaultdict


index_sz = 200
res_sz = 50
indices_ordered = [''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits)
                   for _ in range(10)) for i in range(index_sz)]

res = [pd.Series([random.randint(0,10) for i in range(index_sz)],
                  index = random.sample(indices_ordered, index_sz))
       for i in range(res_sz)]


def your_way(res, indices_ordered):
    dct = defaultdict(list)
    for n in range(len(res)):
        for i in indices_ordered:
            dct[i].append(res[n][i])


def my_way(res):
    dct = defaultdict(list)
    for item in res:
        for string_item, value in item.iteritems():
            dct[string_item].append(value)
```

Gives:

```
%timeit your_way(res, indices_ordered)
160 ms ± 5.45 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit my_way(res)
6.79 ms ± 47.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

This reduces the time complexity of the whole approach because you don't keep going through `indicies_ordered` each time and assigning values, so the difference will become much more stark as the size of the data grows.

Just increasing one order of magnitude:

```
index_sz = 2000
res_sz = 500
```

Gives:

```
%timeit your_way(res, indices_ordered)
17.8 s ± 999 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit my_way(res)
543 ms ± 9.07 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** Now that testing data is available, it is clear that the changes below have no effect on run-time. The described techniques are only effective when the inner loop is very efficient (on the order of 5-10 dict lookups), making it more efficient still by removing some of the said lookups. Here the `r[i]` item lookup dwarfs anything else by *orders of magnitude*, so the optimizations are simply irrelevant.

---

Your outer loop takes 5000 iterations, and your inner loop 20000 iterations. This means that you are executing 100 million iterations in 23 minutes, i.e. that each iteration takes 13.8 μs. That is not fast, even in Python.

I would try to cut down the run-time by stripping any unnecessary work from the inner loop. Specifically:

- convert `for n in range(len(res))` followed by `res[n]` to `for r in res`. I don't know how efficient item lookup is in pandas, but it's better to do it in the outer than in the inner loop.
- move the `score` attribute lookup to the outer loop.
- get rid of `defaultdict` and pre-create the lists and use an ordinary dict.
- avoid dict stores at all and work on the lists directly, pre-creating them in a sequence. Only create a dictionary at the end.
- cache the lookup of the `append` list method, and prepare in advance the `(append, i)` pairs that the inner loop needs.

Here is code that implements the above suggestions:

```
# pre-create the lists
lsts = [[] for _ in range(len(indices_ordered))]
# prepare the pairs (appendfn, i)
fast_append = [(l.append, i)
               for (l, i) in zip(lsts, indices_ordered)]

for r in res:
    # pre-fetch res[n].score
    r_score = r.score
    for append, i in fast_append:
        append(r_score[i])

# finally, create the dict out of the lists
dct = {i: lst for (i, lst) in zip(indices_ordered, lsts)}
```

Comment: Those suggestions make sense but OP should probably keep on working with pandas dataframes and series, not create a list of lists from arrays.

Comment: @EricDuminil I figured as much. I'll delete my answer if someone shows up with a proper suggestion how to do it inside Pandas.

Comment: You don't have to delete anything. I'm sure your tips will improve OP's performance, at least slightly. I guess there are pandas methods that would do the job in a few seconds, though.

Comment: @user4815162342 Thanks for the answer, and yeah I would not want to change the data structured I use, but I edited the question to include some sample data. Hope that helps!

Comment: @EricDuminil I can leave the answer, but sadly it has no effect on the run-time whatsoever. This is because the techniques it describes are only effective when the inner loop is very efficient, making it more efficient still. Here the `r[i]` item lookup dwarfs the cost of attribute lookups and the `res[n]` indexing by *orders of magnitude*.

Answer (score 2):

You *really* should use a [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html).

Here's a way to create the data directly:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import string
index_sz = 3
res_sz = 10

indices_ordered = [''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(3)) for i in range(index_sz)]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(res_sz, index_sz)), columns=indices_ordered)
```

There's no need to sort or index anything. A DataFrame can basically be accessed as an array or as a dict.

It should be much faster than juggling with defaultdicts, lists and Series.

`df` now looks like:

```
>>> df
   7XQ  VTV  38Y
0    6    9    5
1    5    5    4
2    6    0    7
3    0    0    8
4    7    8    9
5    8    6    4
6    2    4    9
7    3    2    2
8    7    6    0
9    8    0    1

>>> df['7XQ']
0    6
1    5
2    6
3    0
4    7
5    8
6    2
7    3
8    7
9    8
Name: 7XQ, dtype: int64

>>> df['7XQ'][:5]
0    6
1    5
2    6
3    0
4    7
Name: 7XQ, dtype: int64
```

With the original size, this script outputs a `5000 rows × 20000 columns` DataFrame 
 in less than 3 seconds on my laptop.

Comment: thanks, but the problem is that, I really have no control over the "list of Series" as this is coming from an outside function someone else wrote, and it is designed in a way that the 5000 Series are created in parallel and each is assigned the same indices in a different order in that process.

Comment: @user5054 there many ways to create a df. Passing an iterator of dicts is fine as well. The third answer should fit, for example.

Comment: I don't actually follow your answer in relation to the clarifications

Comment: @roganjosh: AFAICT, my code produces the same information as OP's simplified code, but the generation is much faster and requires much less memory. It might not fit OP's actual input, but I cannot tell without seeing a working example. The advice still stands : OP's goal is certainly achievable with a DataFrame, and should be done with a DataFrame.

Comment: The OP gives a working example, strip it back a few orders of magnitude

Comment: @roganjosh: That's exactly what I did. OP's code returns a defaultdict of lists, mine returns a DataFrame with the same information. A df can be used as a dict of lists.

Comment: Sorry, you're correct. It's ended up being the same as my answer once I saw my own thought process through to completion, but yours gives the df

Comment: @roganjosh: Fine. Your answer is definitely interesting as well, and well explained. Upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

Use *pandas* magic (with 2 lines of code) on your input list of `pd.Series` objects:

```
all_data = pd.concat([*res])
d = all_data.groupby(all_data.index).apply(list).to_dict()
```

---

Implied actions:

- `pd.concat([*res])` - concatenates all series into a single one preserving indices of each series object ([pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html))
- `all_data.groupby(all_data.index).apply(list).to_dict()` - determine a groups of same index label values upon `all_data.index`, then put each group values into a list with `.apply(list)` and eventually convert grouped result into a dictionary `.to_dict()` ([pandas.Series.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html))

Comment: Does `pd.concat` take care of the different ordering of indices in each item in `res`? (please see my comment in Eric Duminil's answer)

Comment: @user5054, see my explanations